# AngularJS & Ionic Get a file from URI to POST with multipart form

Tags: angularjs, http, post, ionic-framework

I am trying to upload an image to an API with a http POST service multipart form. I only have the URI of the image (image is stored on the mobile device, android or ios)

I am stuck trying to get the File to send. 
I tried

```
File myFile = new File(uri.getPath());
```

But I get this error with File:

```
services.js:2217 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

I tried to get the file with

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(item.file_uri, function (file) {
  fd.append("documento", file);
});
```

(fd is the FormData)
With this I don't get an error but it sends an empty file. The POST request works tho but, as I said, there is no new file there.
I have to send the file inside the formdata with param "documento"

The uri is like this:
    file:///data/data/com.ionicframework.bemywallet910223/files/ifXaEIMG_20160318_225137.jpg

Thank you all for the help!

Comment: i think you are not providing the exact path of the image thats why you are sending empty file to server

Comment: Hello avDOX, did you find a solution for your problem? It would really helpful if you share it. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any solution to this issue ?